# How can a container always be visible when scrolling

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a question whether it is feasible what I am planning. When I scroll down my page, the red-framed container shouldn't disappear but instead stay in the place of the red frame. I have no idea how to do it right now. Here is the relevant part of the code.

thank you in advance for any idea.
R.Eleven

[Screenshot normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNRYO.jpg)

[Screenshot where the container should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kKvv.png)

[it should look like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI5iB.png)

Here the Code

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            // Main Container
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/bg.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  // Bild Container
                  height: 300,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        boxShadow: [
                          //background color of box
                          BoxShadow(
                            color: Color.fromRGBO(
                              33,
                              33,
                              33,
                              1,
                            ),
                            blurRadius: 4, // soften the shadow
                            spreadRadius: 2, //extend the shadow
                            offset: Offset(
                              0.0, // Move to right 10  horizontally
                              0.0, // Move to bottom 10 Vertically
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image:
                                CachedNetworkImageProvider(data['imgUrl'])),
                        color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 100),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ), // Bild
                Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  // Titel Container
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          boxShadow: [
                            //background color of box
                            BoxShadow(
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                33,
                                33,
                                33,
                                1,
                              ),
                              blurRadius: 4, // soften the shadow
                              spreadRadius: 2, //extend the shadow
                              offset: Offset(
                                0.0, // Move to right 10  horizontally
                                0.0, // Move to bottom 10 Vertically
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Text(data['title'],
                              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline),
                        )),
                  ),
                ), // Titel
                Container(
                  child: Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        // Left
                        flex: 4,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              boxShadow: [
                                //background color of box
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                    33,
                                    33,
                                    33,
                                    1,
                                  ),
                                  blurRadius: 4, // soften the shadow
                                  spreadRadius: 2, //extend the shadow
                                  offset: Offset(
                                    0.0, // Move to right 10  horizontally
                                    0.0, // Move to bottom 10 Vertically
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text("Portionen: ",
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .body1),
                                      Text(data['portions'],
                                          style: Theme.of(context)
                                              .textTheme
                                              .body1),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  Text("Zutaten",
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .title),
                                  Text(data['ingredients'],
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .body1),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Expanded(
                        // Right
                        flex: 6,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding:
                              const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, left: 10),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              boxShadow: [
                                //background color of box
                                BoxShadow(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(
                                    33,
                                    33,
                                    33,
                                    1,
                                  ),
                                  blurRadius: 4, // soften the shadow
                                  spreadRadius: 2, //extend the shadow
                                  offset: Offset(
                                    0.0, // Move to right 10  horizontally
                                    0.0, // Move to bottom 10 Vertically
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(255, 255, 255, 1),
                            ),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text("Zubereitung",
                                      style: Theme.of(context)
                                          .textTheme
                                          .body1),
                                  ItemsList(myid: widget.value),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: are you sure normally it's showing correct?

Comment: Try using a `stack`. Divide your content in 2 parts: Entire page and red widget. Keep the red widget on top of the rest of the content. Now when you scroll the red widget should not scroll.

Comment: the screenshot "normal" shows how it looks at the moment. The screenshot "it should look like that" shows what I am planning. The container framed in red should scroll at the beginning, but stop as soon as it comes to the upper edge of the screen. With stack, the container would not scroll at all. But it should scroll up to the top and only then stop.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is Sticky Side Header, try this [flutter_sticky_header](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header) sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_sticky_header/flutter_sticky_header.dart';

import '../common.dart';

class SideHeaderExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const SideHeaderExample({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppScaffold(
      title: 'Side Header Example',
      slivers: [
        _StickyHeaderGrid(index: 0),
        _StickyHeaderGrid(index: 1),
        _StickyHeaderGrid(index: 2),
        _StickyHeaderGrid(index: 3),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _StickyHeaderGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  const _StickyHeaderGrid({
    Key key,
    this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverStickyHeader(
      overlapsContent: true,
      header: _SideHeader(index: index),
      sliver: SliverPadding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 60),
        sliver: SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
              crossAxisCount: 3, crossAxisSpacing: 4.0, mainAxisSpacing: 4.0),
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, i) => GridTile(
              child: Card(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
              ),
              footer: Container(
                color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Text(
                    'Grid tile #$i',
                    style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            childCount: 9,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SideHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const _SideHeader({
    Key key,
    this.index,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final int index;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 4.0),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 44.0,
          width: 44.0,
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
            foregroundColor: Colors.white,
            child: Text('$index'),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```